# How to update object variables from promises closure

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I've got object variables that I want to update inside promises `guzzle` with closure:

```
foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
            $this->facebook[$url] = 0;
            $this->googlePlus[$url] = 0;
            $this->pinterest[$url] = 0;
            $this->twitter[$url] = 0;
            $this->metaResults[$url] = [
                'url' => false,
                'title' => false,
                'desc' => false,
                'h1' => false,
                'word_count' => 0,
                'keyword_count' => 0
            ];

            $that = $this;
            $promise = $client->getAsync($url)->then(function ($content) {
                return $content->getBody()->getContents();
            })->then(function($html) use (&$url, &$that) {
                $that->metaResults[$url] = $this->parseMeta($html);
            });
            $promeses['meta'][$url] = $promise;
        }

        $responses = Promise\Utils::settle($promises)->wait();
```

The problem as you can see above `$that->metaResults[$url] = $this->parseMeta($html);` this is never saved on that object var. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like there are few errors. If you want to use $url and $that shouldn't you pass it in to callbacks registered with the promises's `then` method for first one. Also I think that $this will not be accessible inside the callback registered with the `then()`. Though you will need to check for $this.

```
$promise = $client->getAsync($url)
            ->then(function (ResponseInterface $content) use ($url, $that) {
                return $content->getBody()->getContents();
            })
            ->then(function($html) use ($url, $that) {
                $that->metaResults[$url] = $this->parseMeta($html);
            });
$promeses['meta'][$url] = $promise;
```

[reference](https://github.com/guzzle/promises)